# Import .bak file to a database in DataGrip

Tags: sql-server, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I have a file with .bak file, I want to import this file in my DataGrip.

I have installed the lib from JetBrains `SQL Server Backup And Restore`
Link: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13913-sql-server-backup-and-restore.
It not works, help

Comment: Is there any problem or error? or just you want to know the instruction?

Comment: Dear! yes I want to know the instruction. I'm using Datagrip not SQL Management Studio

Comment: DataGrip is not a SQL Server. You need to connect to a SQL Server to perform the restore, then you'll be able to use DataGrip to query the restored database.

Comment: All the information about the plug-in is provided in the Overview section. But as was mentioned by @TZHX, you should have a running SQL Server instance configured as datasource in DataGrip in order to perform actions advertised by the plug-in. If you have it set up and experiencing issues with the plug-in, you should get in touch with the plug-in author directly. To contact the author, use either Email or Issue Tracker on that page.

Answer (score 1):

To restore from *.bak* file you need:

1. Select the data source where you intend to restore the backup
   [image: selecting data source to restore backup to]
2. Choose .bak file and click *OK*
   [image: locating bak file to restore from]
3. Specify database name and click *OK*
   [image: specifying database name]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. 
I'm on Windows OS (DataGrip 2022.1.4) there is no Backup/Restore option here.
screenshot:  [Screen-Capture](https://ibb.co/TwL0S8Q)

Comment: A bit strange, could you contact [plugin author](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13913-sql-server-backup-and-restore) for your problem investigation?